# EXCEL Get the shift of the person based on date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a formula where the shift of the person will show based on the given date.

So what I hope to achieve is the Persons schedule will show depending on the date.

[image]

Comment: Post data to post body instead of image. Which version of excel do you use? `MINIFS()` will give you desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok if you move the "Date" column to the left in both sheets? If yes, then you can use "VLOOKUP" function for the desired result. I think it'll be much easier. If you need any help regarding VLOOKUP function I'll help you.
Ashgabat.

Comment: You don’t need to move the primary data around - just use index() and match(), then you can do the equivalent of vlookup() when the data is in any order or even in different places.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I know that. But it a bit complicated. I thought using VLOOKUP would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

If your data in Sheet1 is in cells `A1:D10` and your data in Sheet2 is in columns `A:E` then use the following formula in `B2` entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`:
`=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(1,(@$A:$A=Sheet2!$A:$A)*(@$D:$D=Sheet2!$E:$E)*("shift"=Sheet2!$B:$B),0))`
Drag down and to the right.
It looks for a match of 1 for 3 conditions (condition true = 1, false= 0). If at least one of the conditions is false it's multiplied by 0 and results in 0. If all conditions are true it's 1*1*1 = 1. That would be the match. It counts the position of that match in the array and returns that as a result, which equals the row number.
It indexes the column mentioned in the index formula and returns the value of the calculated row number.